# Output most recent date Excel

Tags: excel, max, worksheet-function, date-math, date-manipulation

I'm looking to derive a formula which will output the most recent date between cells CK:CM. My sheet looks like this:

[image]

For row 2, output should be 2021-06-04, row 4 should be 2021-05-06, row 5 should be N/A.

I'm currently using a nested IF statement within a MAX function which returns 00 January 1900 for all rows: `=MAX(IF('Loan Tape'!B2:B51=Data!B2, 'Loan Tape'!CK2:CM51))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused and not sure how column `B` is relevant in your example formula since you didn't mention it (or your `IF` condition) in your explanation.

So outside of of that, if just want the most recent date, for example, for `CK4:CM4`, then you'd simply use `=MAX(CK4:CM4)`.

This works fine even with the rows that have a cell containing the text `N/A`.  It's only an issue when all 3 date cells for that row are 'N/A', in which case it will return `0` (which, if formatted as a date, displays as `1900-01-01`) but a simple `IF` will deal with that, like for row 5:

```
=IF(MAX(CK5:CM5)=0,"unknown",MAX(CK5:CM5))
```

...replacing `unknown` with whatever you want it to return in that case.

[image: screenshot]

If you meant that you needed the most recent date out of all rows for those 3 columns, you'd use `=MAX(CK:CM)` which returns `2021-06-04` using your sample data.